# Paginación mostrando los resultados en php y SQL

Tags: php, sql, paginación

Tengo un problema con la paginación en el código php, La paginación funciona pero los resultados los muestra mal, me explico:
el código obtiene todas las entadas en la página de inicio y luego las va restando, es decir, muestra todas las entradas en inicio por ejemplo 12 y tiene que mostrar 4, al paginar muestra 8 y al paginar otra vez muestra 4, necesito que muestre las entradas de 4 en 4 (p.ej)..

#### Estoy usando este código:

```
  <?php
      require 'vendor/autoload.php';
      $pelicula = new Jflabur\Pelicula;
      $info_peliculas = $pelicula->mostrar();
      $cantidad = count($info_peliculas);
      // Paginación
      // Aqui es donde ajustas los registros
      $elementosPorPagina = 4; 
      $paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
      $inicio = ($paginaActual - 1) * $elementosPorPagina;
  ?>

  <div class="pagination">
  <?php
      $totalPaginas = ceil($cantidad / $elementosPorPagina);
      if ($paginaActual > 1) {
         echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual - 1) . "'>&laquo; Anterior</a> ";
      }
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
        $claseActiva = ($i == $paginaActual) ? 'active' : '';
          echo "<a class='$claseActiva' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a> ";
      }
      if ($paginaActual < $totalPaginas) {
         echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual + 1) . "'>Siguiente &raquo;</a> ";    
      }
      ?>
  </div>  

  <?php
      // Aqui es donde muestra los resultados
      if($cantidad > 0){
        for($x = $inicio; $x < $cantidad; $x++){
          $item = $info_peliculas[$x];
  ?>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1 class="titulo"><?php print $item['titulo'] ?></h1>  
        </div>
        <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>" >
        <div class="panel-body">
              <?php
                $foto = 'upload/'.$item['foto'];
                if(file_exists($foto)){
              ?>
              <img src="<?php print $foto; ?>" class="img-responsive">
          <?php }else{?>
            <img src="assets/imagenes/not-found.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <?php }?>
        </div>
          </a>
      </div>
  <?php
          }
      }else{?>
        <h4>NO HAY REGISTROS</h4>
  <?php }?>
```

Comment: me hubiera gustado ayudarte pero el codigo que presentas es ilegible para mi, ya que tiene php mesclado con html y no esta tabulado o organizado ...